# The type name 'Worksheet' does not exist in the type 'ExcelWorkbook'

Tags: c#, excel

I'm currently working with Visual Studio and writing automation scripts in c# using Selenium and for part of the script I need to read from Excel files. I have all references installed and am using the EPPlus package. This is my excel code within the project.

```
string excelFile = ("test.xls");
FileStream f = File.OpenRead(excelFile);
ExcelPackage pack = new ExcelPackage(f);
ExcelWorkbook.Worksheet sheets = pack.Workbook.Worksheets;
ExcelWorksheets configTab = sheets("Configuration");`
```

the line ExcelWorkbook.Worksheet sheets = pack.Workbook.Worksheets; has an error under Worksheet saying:

> The type name 'Worksheet' does not exist in the type 'ExcelWorkbook'

I can provide any additional information if needed.

Comment: The type is named `ExcelWorksheets`, not `ExcelWorksheet`.

Comment: have you made the references of excel related dlls?try to find which step occured something wrong.

Comment: @MapleStory I have the Microsoft Excel 15 Object library and Microsoft.Csharp added and I believe all the others that matter, I don't think that is the problem

Comment: I changed it but still have the error that it does not exist in the type 'ExcelWorkbook' @PatrickHofman